# Load Required Css on Demand in React Js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am converting one of the bootstrap template into react

as I want to known that is there any way that I load stylesheets on demand

For example 
There are 2 components 
I import the same stylesheets separately in both component

is there anyway to import them once

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a static bundler like Webpack with [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader), all CSS files imported anywhere in your app will be condensed into a single style tag on the main HTML file, which will apply to all elements rendered by your app.  So provided you're outputting a single JS file, you can just remove the second import and achieve the same result.